# Access data inside memory location array

Tags: go, ethereum, go-ethereum

I am trying to parse the following type array in geth to "look inside" and get the info but can not figure out how to do it.

`txs []*types.Transaction`

This type is declared elsewhere in geth as

```
type Transaction struct {
    data    txdata
    hash    atomic.Value
    size    atomic.Value
    from    atomic.Value
}
```

and I am trying to access the data using the following loop but I can't seem to access any of these values.

```
    for _, tx := range *txs {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("transactions in this block - hash: %s and data: ", tx.hash))
    }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how I can access the data in memory locations that is an array

Comment: See the docs with examples: [`atomic.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#Value) only has 2 methods.

Comment: Take The Tour of Go. The given declartion of txs doesn't match how you range over it.

Comment: Im new to go and have take the tour of go but still dont understand how to parse this

Comment: Why are you trying to access unexported values? You should not do this. There's a reason they are unexported.

Comment: Not helpful at all.... answer is below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`*types.Transaction`](https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types#Transaction) has accessor methods:

```
func (tx *Transaction) Hash() common.Hash
func (tx *Transaction) Data() []byte
func (tx *Transaction) Nonce() uint64
func (tx *Transaction) To() *common.Address
```

(and many more)

Read the package documentation and learn Go. Lowercase field names are unexported (private).